# converting from a string to a variable in php

Tags: php

I have written this,

```
<?php
    function get_pounds($var){
    $string ='i have $var pounds';
    return $string;
    }
    $v =100;
   echo get_pounds($v);
   ?>
```

outputs:

```
i have $var pounds
```

I know I can use `""` or `$string ='i have'. $var .'pounds';` to avoid this problem. But take a situation when fetching string from a database. I want it to parse it and make $var as a variable on its own without being part of the string.
say

---

**variable**

---

I have $var pounds

---

My query goes "`select variable from $table;`"

```
return mysql_query($query);
```

This will return a string.
How do I parse it so that my $var is not parsed as a var ?

Answer (score -3):

instead of  `$string ='i have $var pounds';` try  `$string ="i have $var pounds";`

Comment: This will print literally $var instead of its value

Comment: This will print `i have 100 pounds` and not `i have $var pounds`. Isn't it what has been asked?